# gulp-watch breaks when new files are added

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I'm using gulp-watch plugin and would like to copy newly added files in the source to the target destination.

```
watch({glob:SOURCE + '/**/*.js'})
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(DESTINATION));
```

Every time a new file is added into the SOURCE directory I get "Bus error: 10" and the watch breaks without copying the newly added file.

Answer (score 0):

Please you this syntax for adding new files in gulp

```
gulp.task('task_name', function() {
    return watch({
      glob: SOURCE
    }, function(files) {
      return files.pipe(plumber()).pipe(jade()).pipe(gulp.dest(DESTINATION));
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

`gulp.watch` doesn't create a source stream, it triggers on file changes and calls tasks.

Try creating a simple move task alongside a watch task, then trigger the move from the watch. Something like this:

```js
gulp.task('move-js', function() {
  gulp.src('./js-src/**/*.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js-dest'));
});

gulp.task('watch-js', ['move-js'], function() {
  gulp.watch('./js-src/**/*.js', ['move-js']);
});
```

Note that the `watch-js` task has `move-js` as a dependency, this will call the move task whenever the watch is invoked, rather than waiting for something in the watched directory to change.

I repeated the glob for clarity, but that should probably be stored in a variable.

Comment: I'm using gulp-watch plugin https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-watch not the bundled watch that comes with gulp.